# React: Axios.get -> setState(response) -> use state data immediately in another function - how?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have made a functional component, instead of class (too late to change, I've written almost 1000 lines already), and I have a big problem with using data in a function, because the state is not updated when the function is called, so I'm getting an empty array... I'm not sure what can be done here, so that the function doStuffWithIt() is able to use updated states that are not empty.

So basically this is how I have it setup:

```html
    const [objects, setObjects] = useState([])
    const [processedObjects, setProcessedObjects] = useState([])
    
    async function loadData() {
        await axios.all([
            axios.get("/api/objects"),
            ...etc //multiple other axios.get calls
        ]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
            setObjects(responses[0].data)
            ...etc //multiple setStates
        })).catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        loadData()
        doStuffWithIt()
    }, [])
    
    function doStuffWithIt() {
        console.log(objects) // <-- returns empty array []
        
        //process the array with .map function and push the changes into processedObjects with setProcessedObjects,
        //so I can use processed objects as options inside a react-select component
    }
    
    return (
        <Select options={processedObjects} />
    )
```

Note: I will have multiple  components like this, that will need to have the fetched data to be processed and set in another state hook.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code of that function inside effect with needed dependency.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(objects) // <-- returns empty array []
    
    //process the array with .map function and push the changes into processedObjects with setProcessedObjects,
    //so I can use processed objects as options inside a react-select component
}, [objects])
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it.